# Add, remove and set CardView parameters programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing an application using the `RecyclerView` & `CardView` widgets to display the contacts added by the user.

- The application allows the user to add a new card, set the appropriate information (name, phone number & image) to be displayed within the card while the card is being added to the list
- The number set by the user can be dialed to initiate a phone
  call when the card is clicked

[image: add and delete cards recyclerview]

I have created the UI, but I don't know how to go about the aforementioned operations using `RecyclerView`. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you struggling with binding the contact values like name and phone to the `CardView` itself and its `View`s?

Comment: Absolutely Yes @Razor.

Comment: Also, are the widgets within your `CardView` that have the contact name and phone number, are they `TextView`s?

Comment: Not just TextView s, but also an image View. BTW Thanks for the question review!

Comment: One more thing, do you access the contacts from an SQLite database?

Comment: @Razor, No , i created an ArrayList to hold the informations. Kindly advice.

Comment: That's fine. Just note that you may have to alter the `ArrayList<>` as I demonstrated in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind the contacts to the `CardView`, you need to create an `ArrayList<>` to store the contacts in order to bind them. First, create a new class called `Contact.java` and add the following code:

```
public class Contact {
    public String name;
    public int number;

    public Contact(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

This class will make sure that each instance within our `ArrayList<>` has the required values for the name of the contact and phone number. Now, we need to create an adapter class to manage the click events within our `CardView` and to bind the values from our `ArrayList<>` to the `View`s within the `CardView`. Create a new class called `ContactsAdapter.java` and add the following code:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder> {
    public List<Contact> list;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<ContactsAdapter> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Update:
        RelativeLayout item;

        ImageView photo;
        TextView name;
        TextView number;

        public ContactsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            // Update:
            item = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.id_to_rel_layout); // If not, then add one by using android.id="@+id/whatever"

            photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        // Update:

        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do onclick stuff here such as dialing someone
            }
        });

        viewHolder.photo.setImageURI(your_uri);
        viewHolder.name.setText(list.get(position).name);
        viewHolder.number.setText(list.get(position).number);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Now we have to attach the adapter to our `RecyclerView`. In the activity that contains the appropriate `RecyclerView`, add the following code:

```
private List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>;

public void loadContacts() {
    list.add(new Contacts(photoUri, name, number));

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You have successfully binded your contacts with your `CardView`. Tell me how you go.

Comment: Why give the model object a pluralized name? Shouldn't an instance be of a Contact and not a Contacts since it doesn't internally hold a list but a single Contact?

Comment: @MattWolfe that isn't a big deal, i can simply remove the 's'  from the model objects' name.

Comment: @Razor I Deeply appreciate your help, i will go give it a try. But i can't find any onClickListener to dial number entered by the user in your code.

Comment: Is the layout in the `CardView` a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @Razor Yes, a RelativeLayout

Comment: I have updated the question. Have a look in the `ContactViewHolder` class and in the `onBindViewHolder` function for the updated code.

Comment: @Razor, I keep getting an error "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2f0732ba" in onBindViewHolder  viewHolder.number.setText(list.get(position).number);

Comment: How are you initialising the values for your `TextView`s? Are you using the list or hard coded string values?

Comment: Oh...i guess that'll solve the problem. Thanks @Razor